# Resize webview iphone 5

Tags: ios, webview, resize

i'm seeking a method to resize my webview according the current iPhone.

I tried to change the frame of the webview, to check the autolayout etc. but it's not running, I tried other solutions, and i didn't succeed to resize my webview.

I tried for example this but nothing change :

```
    _contenuNews.frame = self.view.frame;
```

I don't want to use

```
    Scale page to fit.
```

I want my webview take all the screen.

Someone to help me ? Thx

Comment: Are you using Storyboards/xibs or do you create the view controllers "by hand"?

Comment: I'm using Storyboard :)

Answer (score 0):

If your webview is added via IB and if you are using autolayout then you can not resize the frame. For this you need to uncheck the autolayout option from IB.

[image]

After that try to resize the frame of your WebView.

Though you didn't want to use scale to fit but it will be good to use scale to fit. It may help other so I am adding it to my answer:

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit =YES;
```

The above code will make sure that the content of UIWebView is loaded inside the view frame.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: sorry, i forgot to answer you.. i uncheck the use autolayout, but it's not running yet.